# my display brightness is dimming automaticly

Tags: arch-linux, xfce, nvidia, brightness

i just installed the proprietary nividia-beta drivers in arch, and my brightness is changing depending on the background, 
black = too dark
white = too bright

Im using arch linux and xfce on a GTX 1050 ti

Answer (score 0):

It may be an effect of Nvidia's "Dynamic Contrast Enhancement", [which can apparently be disabled](https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?38038-Autobrightness-based-on-lightness-of-items-on-screen#post318161) through the Nvidia Control Panel.